# Cancel ongoing call using Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on android caller application through which user can call any person from android watch. Calling any person from watch is easy to implement because we are just passing call intent to phone and call will be happened from phone, Now my question is, is there any way to cancel that ongoing call from Android watch ? can we pass some message to phone and it will cancel that call according to that message ?

Answer (score 0):

This [confirmation timer feature](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html) is a bit different from what you ask, but it will maybe fill your need.